# Opening current folder in VS Code from file explorer URL

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to open the current folder in VS Code using

```
vscode://
```

So far, I have tried

```
vscode://file/{current_folder}
vscode://file/\.
```

and several variations of that, but unfortunately to no avail.

Background:
I am trying to open VS Code using Listary and for that I need to open it using

```
vscode://
```

[Image of Listary config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqtmS.png)